# what does the slang ぱしり mean?

Tags: slang

I've heard this being used around on Japanese tv shows a lot. Usually in high school settings.

Where does this word originate from, and how do I use this in a sentence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ぱしり　is short for 使いっ走り（つかいっぱしり). You see this in high school settings because that's where ぱしり　usually happens.

ぱしり　is when a senior or someone stronger than you abuses their position or power to make you do things. Typically it is when they make you go buy things.

> おいジョンコンビニでジューズ買ってこいよ。 (Yo John, go get me a drink from the convenient
>   store)

Here, John is a "ぱしり".